# How to insert in a cell the name and link of a folder that has just been created in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets-macros

I'd like to create some folders in Google Drive through a script in Google Sheets and then to get the URLs of the new folders to put them in a cell.

I successfully created the folders based on the column "Employee ID" and replaced the values of the column "Employee ID" with the folder hyperlinks.

So I get the 3 folders created in Google Drive: 1,2 and 3, respectively. The problem is that my code repeats the **same name and URL in every row in the Google Sheets** setting the name and URL of the last folder that was created (the folder 3 in this case).

I would appreciate it if you could give me some help with this. This is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if ([1, 2,].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != 1) return;
createEmployeeFolder();
}

function createEmployeeFolder() {
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("1H0i69rE9WO0IAoxhnrFY2YKT_tD50fuX")
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database').getRange('B3:B').getValues()
    .forEach(function (r) {
        if(r[0]) checkIfFolderExistElseCreate(parent, r[0]);
    })
}

function checkIfFolderExistElseCreate(parent, folderName) {
var folder;
var idfolder;
var link;
try {
    folder = parent.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
} catch (e) {
    folder = parent.createFolder(folderName);
    idfolder = folder.getId();
    link = folder.getUrl();
    formula = '=hyperlink("' + link + '",' + folder + ')';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database').getRange('B3:B').setFormula(formula); 
}
}
```

---

Ok I changed my code for this. I can create the folders but the problem is with the **SetFormula** I can't make it work in order to read every row to replace the ID with the URL. It just take the last ID and then it repeats the same ID in all the rows from the range. Please some help! :P

```
 function createEmployeeFolder() {
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("1H0i69rE9WO0IAoxhnrFY2YKT_tD50fuX")
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database').getRange('B3:B').getValues()
    .forEach(function (r) {
        if(r[0]) createFolder(r[0]);
    })
}

function createFolder(folderName) {

  var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("1H0i69rE9WO0IAoxhnrFY2YKT_tD50fuX");

  var projectFolder;

  if (parent.getFoldersByName(folderName).hasNext()) {
    // folder already exists
    Folder = parent.getFoldersByName(folderName).next(); 
  } else {
    Folder = parent.createFolder(folderName);

  }
    var id = Folder.getId();
    var link = Folder.getUrl();
    var formula = '=hyperlink("' + link + '",' + Folder + ')';
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database').getRange('B3:B').setFormula(formula);
    return formula;

}
```

Comment: Note that your function does more than just what its name implies - it also sets the hyperlink formula despite not knowing which range to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that does this for me. It takes a userName and returns a formula for a link to the folder that either existed or was created. This link can be put into a cell using setFormula():

```
function createUserFolder(userName) {

  var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("1H0i69rE9WO0IAoxhnrFY2YKT_tD50fuX");

  if (parent.getFoldersByName(userName).hasNext()) {
    // folder already exists
    userFolder = parent.getFoldersByName(userName).next(); 
  } else {
    userFolder = parent.createFolder(userName);
  }

  var id = userFolder.getId();
  var formula = '=HYPERLINK("https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + id + '","Files")'

  return formula;

}
```

Please note however that you should rethink your code quite dramatically.  onEdit is called for every single change in the spreadsheet which is very wasteful.  Iterating through every single cell in column B is very wasteful.  Using the catch clause in a try to do your critical code is a bad idea.

I would add a dialog or other ui to the sheet for triggering the creation of the folder rather than monitoring the sheet continually.

Comment: Hi!, what's the function of the var "projectFolder"?  And could you tell me please how I can have the setFormula() to check every "folder" go get every URL, it only takes the last one and it repeats the same URL in every row. :C

Comment: projectFolder is left over from my own function, you can ignore it, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The following script creates a folder in drive and a link with the name of the folder within a cell automatically.

```
function createAndHyperlink() {
    var ss, sh, parent, parent2, r, v, thisCell, folder
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    sh = ss.getSheetByName('INSERTTHENAMEOFYOURSHEETHERE')
    parent = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
    parent2 = DriveApp.getFolderById("INSERT-YOURGOOGLEDRIVEFOLDERIDEHERE")
    r = sh.getRange('B3:B')
    v = r.getValues()
    for (var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
        thisCell = sh.getRange(i + 3, 2)
        if (v[i][0] && !thisCell.getFormula()) {
            folder = parent2.createFolder(v[i][0]);
            thisCell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from incomplete refactoring - you split the task of getting the folder id into a separate method, but also split the task of setting the hyperlink into that `Range`-unaware code.

The solution to repeating the last value across all other rows is to fix your refactoring - setting the formulas should be done where the range to write to is known.

```
function createEmployeeFolder() {
  const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("some id");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database');
  const range = sheet.getRange(3, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 2);
  range.getValues().forEach(function (row, index) {
    // Consider checking if this r & c has a formula in the equal size array from getFormulas()
    if(row[0]) {
      var newLink = getLinkForFolderName_(parent, row[0]);
      // Use the current array index to write this formula in only the correct cell.
      range.offset(index, 0, 1).setFormula(
        "=hyperlink(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + row[0] + "\")";
      );
    }
  });
}

function getLinkForFolderName_(root, name) {
  var folder;
  const search = root.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (search.hasNext()) {
    folder = search.next();
    if (search.hasNext())
      console.warn("Multiple folders named '" + name + "' in root folder '" + root.getName() + "'");
  }
  else
    folder = root.createFolder(name);

  return folder.getUrl();
}
```

You should do away with the `onEdit` simple trigger binding since simple triggers cannot create folders (you need authorization for that) - just change the name and install the `on edit` trigger for the new name. Another option is to use a menu option that calls this function. However, one (possible) benefit of using an installed trigger is that all folders will be owned by the same account.